# How to share database connection between different lambda functions

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda

I went through [some articles](http://blog.rowanudell.com/database-connections-in-lambda/) about taking advantage of lambda's container and sharing things like database connection between multiple instances, however, what if I have multiple lambda functions accessing the database and I want to have them share the same connection knowing that these functions call each other, for example, an API gateway calls the `authenticator` lambda function and then calls the `insert user` function, both of these functions make calls to the database, is it possible for them to share the same connection?

I'm using NodeJS but I can use a different language if it would support that.

Comment: It's not possible. Even with container reuse (the article you linked to) you can't count on subsequent invocations sharing the same connection, and concurrent invocations definitely won't share a connection.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion @MarkB, so the best practice I guess is to have all the database queries in the same lambda function to minimise connections is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't share connections between instances. Concurrent invocations do not use the same instance. 
You can however share connections between invocations (which might be executed on the same container/instance). However, there you have to check if you connection is (still) open, in which case you can reuse it. Otherwise open a new one.

If you are worried about too many connections to your db just close the connections when you exit your lambda & instantiate new ones every time. You may also need to think about concurrency if that is a problem. A few weeks ago AWS added the possibility to control concurrency on a per function basis, which is neat.